# Python: Separate the characters at the end of the number

Tags: python, substring

I'm using Python.
How can I separate the characters at the end of the number?
Thing is the characters at the back can be anything. There is no defined separator so I can't use substring.

For example:

> 0.00156984$
> 0.00147273Euro​
> 0.00002836¥
> 0.00156765BTC

End Result:

```
0.00156984  
0.00147273 ​
0.00002836    
0.00156765 

$
Euro
¥
BTC
```

Kind Regards

Comment: The previous version and the edited version seem quite different. Are there separate multiple strings or one huge string?

Comment: Sorry I had problem using the Table feature, I have edited now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Pandas here, then you may use `str.extract`:

```py
df["Number"] = df["String"].str.extract(r'^(\d+(?:\.d+)?)')
df["Text"] = df["String"].str.extract(r'^\d+(?:\.d+)?(.*)$')
```

For a general Python solution, use:

```py
Number = re.findall(r'^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', String)[0]
print(Number)  # 0.00156984
Text = re.sub(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?', '', String)
print(Text)  # $
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try using this

```
s = "0.00156984$"


def my_parser(s):
    split_index = max(map(s.rfind, '0123456789')) + 1
    return s[:split_index], s[split_index:]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(my_parser(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use 're' module to achieve this, check below code for example:

```
import re 

def main_fun(data):
  # '[0-9\.]+' will select all numbers and '.' 
  # & \D will select everything that is not a number.
  search_word = re.search(r'([0-9\.]+)(\D+)', data, re.M | re.I)
  if search_word:
    number = search_word.group(1)
    word = search_word.group(2)
    return (number, word)

data = '0.00147273Euro'

number, word = main_fun(data)

print(number)
print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try `str.extract`

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['0.00156984$', '0.00147273Euro', '0.00002836¥', '0.00156765BTC'], columns=['String'])

df[['Number', 'Text']] = df['String'].str.extract(r'([\d.]+)([^\d]+)')
```

```
    String          Number      Text
0   0.00156984$     0.00156984  $
1   0.00147273Euro  0.00147273  Euro
2   0.00002836¥     0.00002836  ¥
3   0.00156765BTC   0.00156765  BTC
```

Comment: it is dataframe @user2741620, Are u lloking for pandas solution? Or general? What is the structure of the input?